# Linking to content from Image not working when using Views Slideshow

Tags: views, javascript, navigation

When using Views Slideshow the ability to "Link Image To: Content" doesn't seem to create an anchor tag in the HTML. It only seems to be happening on a single slideshow on my site but I can't find anything that would stop it from working.

```
<div class="field-slideshow-slide field-slideshow-slide-1 even first" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; z-index: 2; opacity: 1;">
<img class="field-slideshow-image field-slideshow-image-1" width="950" height="400" alt="" src="http://localhost/lennondesign/sites/default/files/styles/homepage_slideshow/public/pixel%20superallan_0.png" typeof="foaf:Image">
</div>
```

This is the code that's generated from Views. If I change it to link to the original file then it works - have I just stumbled on to an odd bug?

Comment: Strange. Did you rewrite the content of the field ? I'd double check the field properties in Views, making sure there's no custom element or rewriting taking place.

Comment: You could also try changing the theme to a core one and see if the issue goes away.